# Firebase - can't see average time on events tab

Tags: firebase, unity-game-engine, screen, analytics

I'm using firebase analytics on a unity project and I can see only last 30 minutes data from stream view. However i can't see average times spent on screen_views on events tab. I already tested firebase sdk and checked on debug reports, everything works. And also I can see only last 30 minutes data on Stream View section.

Why firebase doesn't show average time on events tab?

Screenshot : 
[image: Events tab]

Answer (score 0):

Sorry. I forgot that data will be shown after a few hours.